# Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.TableRow when start activity

Tags: java, android, xml

i have designed a simple game when i try to start the game activity it shows this error:

```
06-27 04:34:35.177 22455-22455/com.game.circle.thecirclegame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.game.circle.thecirclegame, PID: 22455
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.game.circle.thecirclegame/com.game.circle.thecirclegame.GamePanel}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.TableRow
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

this is my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:background="@color/accent_material_dark">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/abc_color_highlight_material">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Timer : "
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_timer_variable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="timer_variable"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txt_timer" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Score: "
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_timer"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/txt_score" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Score"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/txt_score_variable"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_score"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txt_score" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_score_variable"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:rowCount="6">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/c1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/c2"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c3"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c4"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c5"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c6"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c7"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c8"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c9"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c10"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c11"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c12"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c13"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c14"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c15"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c16"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c17"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c18"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c19"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/c20"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


        </GridLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

the scenario of error as the following:

- Run the App
- Main activity will Appear
- press on the "Start game" button. **which navigate you to the next activity.**
- The error will start

Comment: try to rebuild and rerun the project

Comment: @Anders i did, nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color resource you are using is not found, ie. abc_color_highlight_material. So remove following line from your layout file:

```
  android:background="@color/abc_color_highlight_material"
```

And make tablerow as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:background="@color/accent_material_dark">

      <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    .........
    .........
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem due to
 android:background="@color/abc_color_highlight_material"
 change this one.